# Compiling/using libjpeg for iPhone (iOS 3.0+)?

Tags: objective-c, c, iphone-sdk-3.0, jpeg, libjpeg

I want to use the libjpeg (http://www.ijg.org/) library in an iPhone iOS 3.0 or greater project.  I have tried a few different approaches, but being a bit naive, I'm not really sure how to begin.

I've been playing with parts and pieces of the SDL library project from here http://code.google.com/p/sdl-static/ all to no real working outcomes.

Can anyone link me to a tutorial or give me a push in the right direction?

My ultimate goal is to be able to manipulate the DCT coefficients of jpeg images somewhat similar to this MatLab libjpeg wrapper.
http://www.philsallee.com/jpegtbx

So I would like to start with something like

```
UIImage *cover = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cover.jpg"];
// convert to the libjpeg structs
// do some DCT coefficient manipulations
UIImage *stego = ... // save it back to iOS SDK equivalent image type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the entire library into your project and add the files to XCode. There's a file 'filelist.txt' which describes the minimal set you need to link into your project. Have a look at 'example.c' for how to call the API. I don't see functions to tweak the DCT coefficients - that you'll have to hack in yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up getting the SDL compiled version of the libjpeg to work (so far at least).  I am confused in your approach however because based on the filelist.txt a few of the header files are generated during install.  I suppose I could reverse engineer that file to figure out what I'm missing post mortum, but that sounds painful.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, yes the 'configure' script generates some headers to define things about your system. You can invoke that on the command line, but it's tricky to get configure scripts working when cross-compiling. Have a look at 'install.txt' section 'Configuring the software by hand', which is your situation. You'll need to copy jconfig.txt to jconfig.h and edit the defines.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it working now.  Oh and for others that find this thread, you can access the DCT coefficients in libjpeg using the jpeg_read_coefficients function.  http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libjpeg.jpeg.read.coefficients.1.html